# How can I make a form in Chrome extension show only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension that will, when installed, ask for the API key in the popup.html window. After a user enters and saves the API key, the form should be hidden from displaying next time the extension icon is clicked and only the content below the form should be shown.

Form in my **popup.html** looks like this:

```
<form action="" class="apikey" id="api">
    <input type="text" id="apikey" placeholder="Please enter your API key ...">
    <button type="submit" id="saveKey" form="api">Save</button>
    <a class="hint" href="#">Where can I generate my API key?</a>
</form>
```

The following is the **popup.js** code for hiding the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#saveKey').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#api').hide();
    });
});
```

And the function for saving the API key also located in **popup.js**:

```
function saveKey() {
  // Get a value saved in an input
  var apiKey = $("#apikey").val();
  // Check that the key has been entered
  if (!apiKey) {
    console.log('Error: No value specified');
    return;
  }
  // Save it using the Chrome extension storage API
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': apiKey}, function() {
    // Notify that we saved
    console.log('Your API key was saved.');
  });
}
```

Hiding of the form is taken care of, what I now need to do is prevent the form `#api` from displaying next time the extension icon is clicked, because currently hiding of the form only works after clicking on the Save `button`.

Comment: Maybe first check if the api key is defined and then, if not, show the form, otherwise don't...

Comment: Something in the lines of `chrome.storage.get('apikey', function(object items) { if(x) dontshowform(); else showform(); });`. Please be reminded that I don't know how google chrome extensions work, so I saw the docs and got this up...

Comment: Hi sorry for excavating this :) I am trying to do something similar and I'd sure could use help - is the code of this app available anywhere?

Comment: @Shoshinmas no, sorry. Although the extensions was available in Chrome store for a few years, it's now been ages since I've last seen it being used in the wild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're saving the API key, but I'm assuming your code somewhere else saves it to `localStorage`.

In that case, modify `popup.js` to something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var apiKey = localStorage.getItem('apiKey');

    if (apiKey) { // apiKey was saved previously
        $('#api').hide();
    } else {
        $('#saveKey').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            localStorage.setItem('apiKey', $('#apikey').val());
            $('#api').hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Of course, if you're not saving the API key in `localStorage` but instead save it on a server or whatever, you would just save a flag instead (e.g. `apiKeySaved`) and test for that instead.

Another option (even though it wouldn't change the core of the problem of testing for a value in `localStorage`) would be to have two different HTML documents for the popup and have the background page change it with `setPopup`. The main benefit of doing that is that you end up with two separate documents for two separate goals. It's a bit cleaner when looking at the HTML, but a bit more work since you're adding a background page. Documentation for `setPopup` is [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setPopup).

Comment: I edited my question and added the code which saves the API key. Instead of using localStorage.setItem I'm using the chrome.storage.sync.set, which, if a user has Chrome sync enabled, syncs the stored value across user's Chrome browsers. After implementing your solution, hiding of the #api form seems to work perfectly! :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I keep forgetting about `chrome.storage.sync`… I really need to start using it :) (it never felt super necessary in the extensions I've built)

Comment: Do you have any information on how long is the lifetime of a value saved in the localStorage?

Comment: I don't, but as far as I know, it's permanent until you uninstall the extension.